# Check if coordinates are within a predefined region

Tags: ios, swift, core-location

I want to check if coordinates that I am obtaining using the Location Manager are within a certain region.

1. How can I create a region out of coordinates on swift? I don't want to draw the layer on the map or anything. I would just need to create it in order to check whether my coordinates are inside or outside of the region
2. When created, is there a special method to check whether coordinates are inside this region.

Would be great if you could point me in the right direction.

Comment: If your region is circular, you can try out the contains method of CLCircularRegion.
If your region is a polygon, and you have the coordinates, you can use a brute force approach by using the distance(from:) method of CLLocation.

Comment: How would I set up this region then? I have seen implementation for the circular region, but I haven't seen it for polygons.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be mixing things.

**One thing is:**

How to create a circular region. See [here](https://www.appcoda.com/geo-targeting-ios/). You use this to create a region and then if you drive through this region, or drive away from this region, you get will get a callback.

**The other**

If you purely just want to 'know the distance between two points', then you don't need to use `CLRegion`, just use the [`distance`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocation/1423689-distance) function. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33304446/5175709)

Comment: What I have is a region that is confined by around 500 coordinates and creates a polygon. For this region I want to check whether or not the current coordinate is inside this polygon.